# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: renge is not defined

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm having difficulty in this funciton inside `svelte` script:

```
  const getRange = function (typ) {
    let range = 0;
    if (typ == 0) {
      range = "A-B";
    } else if (typ == 1) {
      range = "B-c";
    } else if (typ == 2) {
      renge = "C-D";
    } else {
      range = "C-D";
    }
    return range;
  };
```

The template is like:

```
    {#each itmes as itme}
               <strong> {getRange(item.typ)}</strong>
              <br />   
    {/each}
```

Howerver I get his error in browser:

```
Projects.svelte:26 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: renge is not defined
    at Array.getRange (Projects.svelte:26)
    at create_each_block (Projects.svelte:161)
    at Object.update [as p] (Projects.svelte:156)
    at update (index.mjs:1057)
    at flush (index.mjs:1025)
```

I'm wondering what is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  When you do a Ctrl-F on the code and find the one single place that a variable called `renge` is used... Where did you define that variable?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `range` once, in the `else if (typ == 2)` clause:

```
const getRange = function (typ) {
    let range = 0;
    if (typ == 0) {
      range = "A-B";
    } else if (typ == 1) {
      range = "B-c";
    } else if (typ == 2) {
      range = "C-D";
    } else {
      range = "C-D";
    }
    return range;
  };
```